# rtcwake: write error

Tags: suspend, wakeup, rtc

I'm trying to send my system to sleep using e.g.

```
rtcwake -v -m disk -s 60
```

and receive the following output

```
rtcwake: RTC wird als UTC interpretiert
UTC wird verwendet.
    delta   = 1
    tzone   = 0
    tzname  = UTC
    systime = 1524206927, (UTC) Fri Apr 20 06:48:47 2018
    rtctime = 1524206926, (UTC) Fri Apr 20 06:48:46 2018
Alarm 0, sys_time 1524206927, rtc_time 1524206926, Sekunden 60
rtcwake: wakeup from "disk" using /dev/rtc0 at Fri Apr 20 06:49:47 2018
suspend mode: disk; suspending system
rtcwake: write error
```

The system seems to start entering the suspend mode but returns back immediately. I'm running  Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS (GNU/Linux 4.13.0-38-generic x86_64). Are there any details, that would help to find the root cause of the problem (dmesg output, /var/log/syslog, ...)?

Thanks in advance,

Bernd

Comment: Have you tried `mem` instead of `disk` with -m switch? I am guessing hibernation is not possible on the machine since there is not enough swap mem, have you checked this? I am guessing that is the reason why it returns immediately.

Comment: Actually in the meantime I have found the problem. After adding 'hpet=disable' to the Kernel paramters, everthing works as expected.

Comment: The hpet trick does not work for me... :-/

Comment: `hpet=disable` works for me, too. Added it to `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` in `/etc/default/grub` on my debian server